# jQuery UI - autocomplete: ul for every category

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I implemented this code ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gWMv/157/)) to categorize the autocomplete. As I have quite a lot of possible entries I would like to restructure the autocomplete list. At the moment all entries are in one vertical dropdown divided by the category names. I would like to put all category blocks in a row so that it looks somehow like [this](https://forum.jquery.com/viewImage.do?fileId=14737000005517443&forumGroupId=14737000000003003). All I need is to insert a `<ul>` before every category (see code below). But how can I insert the `</ul>` after the last `li` element of a category?
I began with the replacement of the $.each function. But now I am done. Don't know how to contine. Could you please help me?

```
for(i = 0; i < sortedItems.length; ++i) {                           
    if (sortedItems[i]['category'] != category) {
        category = sortedItems[i]['category'];
        ul.append("<ul class='xy'><li class='ui-autocomplete-group'>" + category + "</li>");
    }
    self._renderItemData(ul, sortedItems[i]);
}
```